# cPanel User Filter email rules - using regex to filter/move emails "older than x days"

Tags: regex, email, cpanel

**cPanel** Version:  Unsure

**Issue**
I want to create a filter/rule that will move messages over X days old.
Basically I send emails that are alerts for other tasks through outlook to a specific email on my phone, I need to be able to automatically have the emails move/archive after 2 days, then if possible a second rule to then delete after 21 days.

Using calendar is not an option as these events are triggered either through a calendar reminder or from another VBA source.

I had thought that using the following may work, but I don't know of the Regex string I would need.

Rule:  `Any Header / Matches Regex`

Any advice, direction is appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is going to be more complex than just regex. Since the date you want is variable, the regex has to be changed every day. Before we continue, are you able to do that? Otherwise let's think of a different solution.

Comment: Thank you Vasili, if it can't be done, I'm ok with that. :)  To change it every few days would be pointless as I'm wanting to automate my system :)